# SUMIF by using Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's assume I have an excel table with three columns:

```
 Hours     Loadfactor      Emissions   
  1           0.99            100
  4           0.956           50  
  3           0.91            26
  2           0.01            500
  2           0.0945          120
```

if Loadfactor >0.90 but <0.95  then extract these numbers make a new table and sum the emissions and hours.

How would i do that with python 3 coding?
** Sorry this might be a simple problem, but i am just novice in coding

Comment: are you using pandas or data frame for same ? or you want to create sql table directly ?

Comment: I am trying to create sql table directly by using python. Thanks